# area between two curves . not able to plot the curves

Tags: area

I have to find the area between the curves $x^2=y^3$ and $x=y$. 
How do I plot the curve $x^2=y^3$?. 
I have no experience if working with such curves. 
The only thing i have been able to do till now is find the intersection points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$

Comment: Please help guys . I have no idea of how to plot that curve

Comment: You can always use [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion . i asked this question as i wanted to know about the nature of the curve and what this curve is called. and how to plot it if i get it in my exam?

Comment: Taking the cuberoot on each side you get $y=x^{\frac {2}{3}}$.

Comment: is y=x^(2/3) a parabola?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the LHS is non-negative so $y \geq 0$. Also note that if you replace $x$ with $x$, then the $y$ value doesn't change, so this graph is even (reflective over $y$-axis). Thus, if you graph $y=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ and reflect over the $y$-axis, you get your plot of $x^2=y^3$. Use Desmos or Geogebra (both online graphing calculators) if you don't know how to graph this.